# What am I doing wrong in trying to deploy with the Force.com Migration Tool (ANT)

Tags: ant, build, migration, salesforce

I'm currently trying to work my through a SalesForce.com tutorial on "[Deploying with the Force.com Migration Tool (ANT)](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2008/08/06/deploying-with-the-forcecom-migration-tool-ant/comment-page-1/#comment-2461)".

I’m sure I’m missing something… possibly because my knowledge and experience with Ant has been very limited.

I created a new Java Project and copied the Sample directory from `salesforce_ant_20.0.zip` into it. I modified build.properties and ran `build.xml` in eclipse to test this. That all worked fine.

So, I created Sandbox1 in the `src` directory and copied `package.xml` from my SFDC project into it. I then copied build.properties and `build.xm`l from `sample` into the `src` directory. Now, when I went to run `build.xml`, it complained about the deployRoot `mypkg` not existing. I changed the deployRoot to `Sandbox1` and tried to test again. Below is the result:

```
Buildfile: D:\education\sfdc\Deploy\src\build.xml
test:
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request Id for the current deploy task: 04sA0000002GwsGIAS
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request…
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Completed

BUILD FAILED
D:\education\sfdc\Deploy\src\build.xml:14: FAILURES:
Error: package.xml(Account):An object ‘Account’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(AccountContactRole):An object ‘AccountContactRole’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Activity):An object ‘Activity’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Asset):An object ‘Asset’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Campaign):An object ‘Campaign’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(CampaignMember):An object ‘CampaignMember’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Case):An object ‘Case’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(CaseContactRole):An object ‘CaseContactRole’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Contact):An object ‘Contact’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(ContentVersion):An object ‘ContentVersion’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Contract):An object ‘Contract’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(ContractContactRole):An object ‘ContractContactRole’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Event):An object ‘Event’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Idea):An object ‘Idea’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Lead):An object ‘Lead’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Error: package.xml(Opportunity):An object ‘Opportunity’ of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

I case it helps:

(1) `/src/sandbox1` only contains the file `package.xml` from a different functional SalesForce project in Eclipse.

This file says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <members>UserLicense</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DataCategoryGroup</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>unfiled$public</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/Large_Invoice_Template</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/MarketingProductInquiryResponse</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SUPPORTSelfServiceNewCommentNotificationSAMPLE</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SUPPORTSelfServiceNewUserLoginInformationSAMPLE</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SUPPORTSelfServiceResetPasswordSAMPLE</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SalesNewCustomerEmail</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportCaseAssignmentNotification</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportCaseCreatedPhoneInquiries</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportCaseCreatedWebInquiries</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportCaseResponse</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportEscalatedCaseNotification</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportEscalatedCaseReassignment</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportSelfServiceNewLoginandPassword</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SupportSelfServiceResetPassword</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Letterhead</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>ApexDevNet</members>
        <name>RemoteSiteSetting</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>unfiled$public</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Scontrol</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <version>20.0</version>
</Package>
```

The `build.xml` from the Java/Ant-based Force.com Migration Tool says:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>

<!-- Test out deploy and retrieve verbs for package 'mypkg' -->
<target name="test">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "mypkg" package -->
  <sf:deploy 
            username="${sf.username}" 
            password="${sf.password}" 
            serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
            deployRoot="mypkg"
    />
  <mkdir dir="retrieveOutput"/>
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="MyPkg"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve an unpackaged set of metadata from your org -->
<!-- The file unpackaged/package.xml lists what is to be retrieved -->
<target name="retrieveUnpackaged">
  <mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="unpackaged/package.xml"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve all the items of a particular metadata type -->
<target name="bulkRetrieve">
  <sf:bulkRetrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" metadataType="${sf.metadataType}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve metadata for all the packages specified under packageNames -->
<target name="retrievePkg">
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="${sf.pkgName}"/>
</target>

<!-- Deploy the unpackaged set of metadata retrieved with retrieveUnpackaged -->
<target name="deployUnpackaged">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
</target>

<!-- Deploy a zip of metadata files to the org -->
<target name="deployZip">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" zipFile="${sf.zipFile}" pollWaitMillis="1000"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code & running tests for code in directory -->
<target name="deployCode">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" directory, running the tests for just 1 class -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="codepkg">
    <runTest>SampleDeployClass</runTest>
  </sf:deploy>
</target>

<!-- Shows removing code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
<target name="undeployCode">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="removecodepkg"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows retrieving code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
<target name="retrieveCode">
  <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" retrieveTarget="codepkg" unpackaged="codepkg/package.xml"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code, running all tests, and running tests (1 of which fails), and logging. -->
<target name="deployCodeFailingTest">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" package, running all tests -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="codepkg" runAllTests="true" logType="Debugonly"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows check only; never actually saves to the server -->
<target name="deployCodeCheckOnly">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="codepkg" checkOnly="true"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve the information of all items of a particular metadata type -->
<target name="listMetadata">
  <sf:listMetadata username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" metadataType="${sf.metadataType}"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve the information on all supported metadata type -->
<target name="describeMetadata">
  <sf:describeMetadata username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"/>
</target>
```

Any idea what I did wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The statement **but was not found in zipped directory** is an issue that has to do with the folder names you are using. If you are using custom folders instead of codepkg or mypkg etc, you need to change the names in  **retrieveTarget="codepkg" unpackaged="codepkg/package.xml"** to reflect the new names in each of your targets. Check the image turned link for this explanation https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH40d.jpg[1]

Comment: I know this is old but this helped me realize how much SF deployment is dependent on file names. I changed a field name and didn't update the file name. Updated file name and the deploy worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The errors indicate that your package.xml is referencing components that don't have corresponding files in the directory structure.  Either remove those references from package.xml or add the missing custom object files.

If that doesn't work, could you edit your question to include a directory listing for Sandbox1?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the sparse instructions on the tutorial, those files shouldn't be in the directory structure.  As I understood it, I was to create a new project in Eclipse (not specifically a salesforce project) and create a new folder called "Sandbox1" in "src" and then put package.xml in Sandbox1.  Package.xml is an unedited package.xml from a functional salesforce project.  That is the only file in Sandbox1... Maybe I was too literal.  I'm going to try creating a second salesforce project to see if that helps.

Comment: No... that didn't help at all.  I'm sure there is at least a step or two missing...

Comment: Can you remove everything but the <members>*</members> element for the CustomObject type and try again?  Also, what are you trying to deploy (logically)?  Do you actually have changes you're trying to make or are you just seeing if you can get things to work?  Have you successfully performed a retrieve?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you mean by removing "everything"  Do you mean everything in that <type> element or everything in the file?  I am trying to deploy a SalesForce developer environment that I created just for working on tutorials.  There are a few changes from the defaults in the environment.  I have successfully retrieved the data using the SalesForce IDE and I have also used the SalesForce ID to deploy this to a second development environment.  Currently, I am just seeing if I can get things to work.

Comment: Your package.xml is making explicit references to objects such as Account, Contact, Lead, etc.  The metadata API looks at that file and then expects corresponding files for those objects.  The error you're getting says those files don't exist.  The workaround is to remove references to those missing files.  So your XML for CustomObject could be: <types><members>*</members><name>CustomObject</name></types>.

Answer (score 0):

Your build file defaults to "deploy" from your machine to the server.   This only works if you have content on your machine.  Run a "retrieveUnpackaged" first.  This will get everything on the server specified in the package.xml file.  Then you can modify the results and deploy.

Personally, I only use the type of package.xml you show above for backup purposes.  I keep one package.xml file will everything listed (using "*" plus standard objects) to retrieve the entire contents.  I never use these results to make changes on the server because the eventual "deploy" will take forever.

Instead, create a package.xml file to get just the files you need to work on.  Then make your code changes and then deploy with this smaller package.

Answer (score 0):

Your package file is using an old version of the API:

```
<version>20.0</version>
```

And I'm pretty sure that version doesn't support everything you are doing in there.

quick edit: 36 is the current version I think.
edit2: Man this is an old question, how did I get here?

Answer (score 0):

It is too late. But the issue here is very small I believe, Put `allowMissingFiles="true"` in the  task. What this will do is if it wont find the files in the directory where your build.xml is poiniting it will still allow the deployment. Migration tool does not allow to mention the components in the package.xml if they are not in the directory and a workaround to that is using above option.

Even if you will have a package.xml to retrieve all the components from one org and you only have 2 classes to deply, the same package file will work with allowmissingfiles=true option.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone looking for the solution to this issue. It is quite a basic issue, you need to have all your files in the same directory where your package.xml is. for example, if you are deploying your metadata from

> deploy directory/folder

Than your package.xml and the other file should be part of this folder.

> deploy folder will be having below structure

```
    package.xml
    objects
       --> Product2.object
       --> Account.object
       --> Opportunity.object
       --> ***
    classes 
    other metadata
```

This issue comes when you are trying to deploy metadata without having these files as part of your root directory.